# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest - Ошибка при запуске томката

Tags: java

у меня довольно не большой код:

вот мои зависимости в pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.musa.spring.mvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spring_MVC</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Spring_MVC Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>



  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency><!--добавляем спринг MVC-->


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency><!-- добавляем JSTL для views -->





  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Spring_MVC</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

вот мой web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>Spring_MVC</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering />

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name><!--даем имя сервлета-->
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class><!--вот сам готовый сервлет-->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value><!--путь к контекстным данные-->
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet><!--тут мы создаем уже сделанный за нас сервлет, который будет принимать данные от клиента-->

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern><!--указываем url на который должен срабатывать сервлет. в данном случае на любой url-->
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

и вот сам код контролера

```
package org.musa.spring.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;


//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller// один из видов компонента,отвечающий за создание контроллеров. при сканировании он обозначится как компонент контролера
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/")//аннотация для связки url пути, с вызываемой view
    public String showFirstView(){
        return "first-view";//возвращаем имя view. а префикс WEB-INF/view и суффикс .jsp добавится само так как мы это прописли в web файле
    }

    @RequestMapping("/askDetials")//свяжем этот контроллер с url /askDetails
    public String askEmployeeDetails(){
        return "ask-emp-details-view";//вернем нашу вью с формой опроса
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showDetails")
    public String showEmptDetails(HttpServletRequest request, Model model){//HttpServletRequest - имеет
        // всю инфу о запросе. а Model это контейнер для данных, которые мы можем передавать куда угодно

        String empName = request.getParameter("employeeName");//берем парамет переданный ему через форму
        empName = "Mr. " + empName;//изменяем это имя, добавив Mr

        model.addAttribute("nameAtribute", empName);//добавим в модель атрибут, под именем
        // nameAtribute, со значением перменной empName

        return "show-emp-details-view";//возвращает вью с информацией введеной в форму
    }


}
```

пытался поменять зависимости и версию томкат, но не сработало при этом, до использования HttpServletRequest все работало. использую беслптную версию idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не находится зависимость во время выполнения, потому что вы указали область видимости `provided` — доступно только во время компиляции. Поставьте область видимости в `compile` или уберите совсем (приоритетнее) и будет вам счастье!

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! сервер действительно заработал

Comment: но возникла другая проблема, когда я открываю сайт по url 
http://localhost:8080/org.musa.spring.mvc/showDetails?employeeName=Musa
то вылезает ошибка 
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Comment: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1018)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:902)
 jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:683)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:884)
 jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:792)

Comment: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Comment: а все все, решил проблему, я используя томкат 10, а javax только для томкат 9